# cut suffix (.csv) from bash variable

Tags: bash

I need to add the date to these csv files.
This is what i get when I ls on the directory.

```
 ls -1 *Limit*
 comeLimitChanges.csv
 andLimitSnapshot.csv
 playLimitChanges.csv
 withLimitSnapshot.csv
 usChanges.csv
 dannyLimitSnapshot.csv
```

Here is the script.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 DATE=$(date +%Y%m%d)
 for i in *Limit*
 do

 ddotcsv="$i.$DATE.csv"
 echo "$i" "$ddotcsv"
 sleep 1
 done
```

Here are the results - I need to take the csv off the suffix of end, and don't want to use cut.
There has to be a better way than echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1

```
 comeLimitChanges.csv.20171002.csv
 andLimitSnapshot.csv.20171002.csv
 playLimitChanges.csv.20171002.csv
 withLimitSnapshot.csv.20171002.csv
 usChanges.csv.20171002.csv
 dannyLimitSnapshot.csv.20171002.csv
```

I need this :

```
 comeLimitChanges.20171002.csv
 andLimitSnapshot.20171002.csv
 playLimitChanges.20171002.csv
 withLimitSnapshot.20171002.csv
 usChanges.20171002.csv
 dannyLimitSnapshot.20171002.csv
```

~
~

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), the [suffix substring removal form, `${var%suffix}`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) to remove `csv` suffix before appending your date (which I renamed to a lowercase variable, since allcaps are usually used for global variables in shell):

```
#!/bin/bash
today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
for i in *Limit*; do
    ddotcsv="${i%csv}$today.csv"
    echo "$i $ddotcsv"
    sleep 1
done
```